# Bounded positioning of hypercubes

Tags: hypercube

I have the following question:

Let be (C_n) a sequence of m-dimensional hypercubes such that the series over the volumes of this cubes converges. I assume that it's possible to place those cubes in the m-dimensional space in such a way that those are pairwise disjoint and contained in a bounded set. However, I do not see how to prove that. Does somebody know a referecne or a proof?

Comment: Can you solve the 2-dimensional case where there is a square of side $1/n$ for each $n$? The total area is $\pi^2/6$.

Comment: The case $m=2$ is discussed in Stefan Hougardy, On packing squares into a rectangle, Computational Geometry, Volume 44, Issue 8, October 2011, Pages 456-463, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772111000319

Comment: Abstract We prove that every set of squares with total area $1$ can be packed into a rectangle of area at most $2867/2048=1.399\dots$ . This improves on the previous best bound of $1.53$. Also, our proof yields a linear time algorithm for finding such a packing.

Comment: Thank you very much, the paper is amazing.

Answer (score 2):

This can be generalized:

Let $(C_n)$ be a sequence of sets of $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\sum_n \text{diam}(C_n)^m=S<\infty$. Then we can find disjoint sets $(D_n)_n$ such that $D_n$ is a translate of $C_n$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$ is bounded.

To prove that, reorder the sets $C_n$ so that the sequence $d_n:=\text{diam}(C_n)$ is decreasing. Now consider a ball $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ of volume $4^m S$. Then we can find by recursion a sequence of points $p_n\in B$ such that for any $i<j$ we have $d(p_i,p_j)>2d_i$. To do this we just need to choose $p_n\in B$ outside the closed balls $B(p_1,2d_1),B(p_2,2d_2),\dots,B(p_n,2d_n)$: this is possible because, if $m$ is Lebesgue measure, $m(B)=4^mS=\sum_{i=1}^\infty(2\text{diam}(C_i))^m\geq\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(4\text{diam}(C_i)^m)>\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}m(B(p_i,2d_i))$.

Then choose $D_n$ to be some translate of $C_n$ containing $p_n$. Clearly $\bigcup_n D_n$ is bounded, and the $D_i$ are disjoint because for any $i<j$, $d(p_i,p_j)>2\text{diam}(C_i)\geq \text{diam}(C_i)+\text{diam}(C_j)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand.